# Get Specific Field (Json/PHP)

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get a specific filed from the below json response. I am using Amazon SNS and I am wanting to get the outputs key variable ("key" : "4177/media/test1.mp4") and only return 4177. So basically I am wanting to get whatever is before the first / on output key variable. How would I go about this? Thanks for time in advance.

```
    {
    "state" : "COMPLETED",
    "version" : "2012-09-25",
    "jobId" : "1443105433825-ax3k5c",
    "pipelineId" : "1442869133716-ncyq63",
  "input" : {
    "key" : "sample.mp4",
    "frameRate" : "auto",
    "resolution" : "auto",
    "aspectRatio" : "auto",
    "interlaced" : "auto",
    "container" : "auto"
  },
  "outputs" : [ {
    "id" : "1",
    "presetId" : "1443042941302-mvvgq6",
    "key" : "4177/media/test1.mp4",
    "thumbnailPattern" : "4177/thumbs/test1-{count}",
    "rotate" : "auto",
    "status" : "Complete",
    "statusDetail" : "The input file for this job contains 6 audio channels and the preset is configured for 2 audio channels. Amazon Elastic Transcoder audio-channel mapping may not result in the desired audio.",
    "duration" : 6,
    "width" : 1280,
    "height" : 720
  } ]
}
```

I am grabbing json by $msgs =  json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

Comment: `$msgs['outputs'][0]['key']`.  `$msgs['outputs']` is an array of objects.  You can loop over it if you expect more than just one object.

Comment: This did not work, however, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 $a =' {
"state" : "COMPLETED",
"version" : "2012-09-25",
"jobId" : "1443105433825-ax3k5c",
"pipelineId" : "1442869133716-ncyq63",
 "input" : {
"key" : "sample.mp4",
"frameRate" : "auto",
"resolution" : "auto",
"aspectRatio" : "auto",
"interlaced" : "auto",
"container" : "auto"
  },
  "outputs" : [ {
"id" : "1",
"presetId" : "1443042941302-mvvgq6",
"key" : "4177/media/test1.mp4",
"thumbnailPattern" : "4177/thumbs/test1-{count}",
"rotate" : "auto",
"status" : "Complete",
"statusDetail" : "The input file for this job contains 6 audio channels and the preset is configured for 2 audio channels. Amazon Elastic Transcoder audio-channel mapping may not result in the desired audio.",
"duration" : 6,
"width" : 1280,
"height" : 720
 } ]
}';
    $c = json_decode($a);
    $d =  $c->outputs[0]->key;

    $e = explode("/",$d);
    echo $e[0];// output is 4177
```

Comment: I am using $a =  json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

 $c = json_decode($a);
    $d =  $c->outputs[0]->key;

    $e = explode("/",$d);
    echo $e[0];// output is 4177 and it is current not working, any input? Response is blank.

Comment: What are you getting from file_get_contents()??

Comment: I am using amazon SNS service which basically posts the json ouput above.

Comment: judst do print_r(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); and see what you are getting

Comment: Ok, so now I have it working, however, it is pulling test.mp4 instead of 4177. Any help appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90553/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-nugget).